# Error message on return value assignment

Tags: c

My code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdarg.h>

 char * callMe(char *buf_test, const char *fmt, ...)
 {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
   vsnprintf(buf_test, sizeof(buf_test), fmt, ap);
   va_end(ap);
   return buf_test;
 }

 int main()
 { 
   char buf_t[100];
   int test_flag =1;
   buf_t = callMe(buf_t, "Test successful : %d", test_flag);
   printf("\n\n Result = %s", buf_t);
 }
```

Error:

```
error: array type 'char [100]' is not assignable
  buf_t = callMe(buf_t, "Test successful : %d", test_flag);
  ~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `char [100]` is not assignable. You cannot assign to a `char [100]`.

Comment: `sizeof(buf_test)` this will give the size of the pointer, not the array. Learn about arrays and functions.

Comment: Change return type to `void`. (e.g `void callMe(` ) and delete `return buf_test;`

Comment: I have to return char *. I heard from my peers that snprintf is very expensive function so you should always return char *.

Comment: Then have you asked your peers about the problem you encounter when following their advice? Maybe they know the answer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to an array. You'll need to say something like this:

```
char *result = callMe(buf_t, "Test successful : %d", test_flag);
printf("\n\n Result = %s", result);
```

You've also got a problem with this line:

```
vsnprintf(buf_test, sizeof(buf_test), fmt, ap);
```

`buf_test` is delcared as a `char*` so applying `sizeof` to it will return the size of a pointer. Since you're getting "Test su` back it implies that the pointer size is 8 bytes. Although the variable points to an array the compiler has no way of inferring this.

What you need to so is pass the size of the buffer into the function:

```
char * callMe(char *buf_test, size_t size, const char *fmt, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   va_start(ap, fmt);
   vsnprintf(buf_test, size, fmt, ap);
   va_end(ap);
   return buf_test;
}
```

and then pass the size when you make the call:

```
callMe(buf_t, sizeof(buf_t), "Test successful : %d", test_flag);
```

The compiler will be able to work out the size of the array here because it has access to the full definition of the variable.

Comment: Plus you don't even need a return value because `buf_test` will already be modified.

Comment: I have to return char *. I heard from my peers that snprintf is very expensive function so you should always return char *.

Comment: @Rock26 - It is returning a `char*`. The problem is with what you are assigning it to. You cannot assign to an array in C, and this is why you get the error.

Comment: @Rock26 *"I heard from my peers that snprintf is very expensive function so you should always return char *."* That makes no sense at all. You are already calling `vsnprintf` and paying the price. Returning pointer won't make it more efficient. Don't apply programming advice blindly if you don't know why they give you the benefit.

Comment: @ Sean: I got your point. I modified my code accordingly but I didn't get expected result. My output is : "Result = Test su" instead of "Test Successful : 1".

Answer (score -1):

As the error indicates, you cannot assing the result to an array. Instead, you can use a pointer by changing this line :

```
 buf_t = callMe(buf_t, "Test successful : %d", test_flag);
```

to :

```
 char *success;
 success = callMe(buf_t, "Test successful : %d", test_flag);
```

and therefore modify your `print` statement to :

```
printf("\n\n Result = %s", success);
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I modified my code and it worked. But I could not get expected result. My output is : "Result = Test su" instead of "Test Successful : 1"

Comment: @Rock26 probably check the line `vsnprintf(buf_test, sizeof(buf_test), fmt, ap);` so that you are sure that `buf_test` has the correct value?